# How can I draw shells with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

At first, I try to draw a cylinder which is much different from what I want....

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{-30}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{90}{90}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [tdplot_rotated_coords,
    scale=3,
    mdc/.style={fill=blue, color=blue,draw=none, opacity=.4,line join=round},
    length/.style={<->,thick,line cap=round}]
  \def\d{1}
  \def\r{\d*.45}

    % Cylinder 
  \foreach \t in {0,12,...,348}
    \draw[mdc] ({cos(\t   )*\r+\d/2},  0, {sin(\t   )*\r+\d/2}) % side vertice of cylinder
            -- ({cos(\t+12)*\r+\d/2},  0, {sin(\t+12)*\r+\d/2})
            -- ({cos(\t+12)*\r+\d/2}, \d, {sin(\t+12)*\r+\d/2})
            -- ({cos(\t   )*\r+\d/2}, \d, {sin(\t   )*\r+\d/2})
            -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am curious to know that it is possible to draw shell figures with TikZ (like bellow pictures), but the above code and figures below are far different from what I want....

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible but rather than asking people to do all of the work for you you should show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: OK thank you, I try to draw a cylinder, but there is much different between what I have and what I want.

Comment: Instead of`TikZ` you could try with [`Asymptote`](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/3D%20graphs/index.html)

Comment: Related tikz example: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/spherical-polar-pots-with-3dplot/

Comment: Ti*k*Z is not a good choice for this as it only draws in 2D. You can fake 3D in simple cases. Also, what do you want? If you don't want either what your code produces or the figures shown at the bottom of your post, how do we know what other non-specified thing you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code, which may not be perfect:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
pics/.cd,
shell/.style = {
    code = {
      \path [top color = black!25, bottom color = white]
        (0,.05*6/3) ellipse [x radius = 3-.05, y radius = 2-.032];
      \path [left color = black!25, right color = black!25, middle color = white]
        (-3,0) -- (-3,-2) arc (180:360:3 and 2)
               -- (3,0) arc (360:180:3 and 2);
      \foreach \r in {225,315}
        \foreach \i [evaluate = {\s=30;}] in {0,2,...,30}
          \fill [black, fill opacity = 1/50]
            (0,0.2) -- (\r+\s-\i:3 and 2) -- ++(0,-2)
            arc        (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:3 and 2) -- ++(0,2) -- cycle;
      \foreach \r in {45,135}
        \foreach \i [evaluate = {\s=30;}] in {0,2,...,30}
          \fill [black, fill opacity = 1/50]
            (0,0.2) -- (\r+\s-\i:3 and 2)
            arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:3 and 2)  -- cycle;
      \path [top color = white, bottom color = white]
        (0,.05*6/3) ellipse [x radius = 2-.05, y radius = 4/3-.05*4/3];
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0,0,0) pic {shell} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: shell]

Comment: Please post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), instead of pieces to put togheter...

Comment: Isn't this part of Mark's answer to another question?